# Is it possible to call geom_smooth to groups within groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am exploring some relationships in from a lab experiment and having trouble figuring out how to fit linear `geom_smooth` elements to groups within groups.

[Here are some data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jd5iULU105ZHIsZF90PNWhfcGP23LJCz/view?usp=sharing), the head of those data (called `reprex.code` in example), and a plot of where I am at now (linked as I don't yet have permission to insert images in-line:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  id        x     y group treatment
  <fct> <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>    
1 3.3       1  3.5  b1    zone.3   
2 3.3       2  1.95 b1    zone.3   
3 3.3       3  1.53 b1    zone.3   
4 3.3       4  1.68 p1    zone.3   
5 3.3       5  5.27 p1    zone.3   
6 3.3       6  4.20 p1    zone.3  

reprex.code %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x,
                           y = y,
                           color = id)) + 
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = x,
                            y = y,
                            col = group),
          method = "lm",
          se = FALSE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(reprex.code$x)) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Plot x by y, with grouped geom_smooth function]

This currently renders a linear `geom_smooth` for each of my groups (a total of 5).  What I'd like to do is add another group within that group; resulting in a `geom_smooth` for each of the 6 id factors within the group variable (rendered as colors in the plot linked above).  That would result in a total of 6 lm fits within each of the 5 groups - a total of 30 lms.

Comment: Can't you just use `color = interaction(group, id)`?

Comment: That did it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per mikeck, the solution was to specify `color = interaction(group, id) in the`geom_smooth` call.